# collapse transition not working with angular's UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a div which will show / hide when a button is clicked.  The [UI Bootstrap page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) shows a nice simple example that uses a css transition.

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv7tws10/) where I copy their code, almost exactly (slight change to make html syntax highlighting work, and a line to declare my "app" in the js).

As you can see, it doesn't work as in the example -- there is no transition.  Why not?  Maybe a css transition rule is needed -- but isn't that part of what bootstrap.css provides?

---

for posterity, the equivalent html file from the fiddle would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="my_app">
    <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
        <hr />
        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the equivalent .js would be:

```
var my_app = angular.module('my_app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

my_app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I actually ran into this problem just yesterday. I resolved this issue by downgrading ui-bootstrap to version 0.12.0. I think there is a bug is 0.13.0 that makes the animation not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just downgrade the ui-bootstrap version to 0.12.0. There is a bug in 0.13.0 that makes the animation not work.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="my_app">
    <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
        <hr />
        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS can stay the same. I just modified the ui-bootstrap version in the html code.

Here is the updated fiddle as well - https://jsfiddle.net/xv7tws10/5/

Edit: See Premchandra's response below. Apparently you have to include ng-animate in order to get collapse animation to work in angular 1.3.

Comment: Aha.  No big deal then I guess.  Thanks!

Comment: See Premchandra Singh's answer. Need ngAnimate module for animation to work.

Answer (score 39):

Angulajs UI Bootstrap 0.13.0 need ngAnimate module for animation. Register ngAnimate it will work. [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3676)

[`Original plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/8n1ONjGvNeJWh7kVkgQc?p=preview)

[`Modified, animation working plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/H6AZ62eBHbsDNIY6ckVD?p=preview)

Comment: Working for Angular 1.5!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a version limit up until where this stops to animate.

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/csprsL2f/13/)** to see it working as you want it to, but with the newest versions it will only work with.

```
<html !DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body  ng-app="my_app">
<br>
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
    <hr />
    <div collapse="isCollapsed" >
        <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.8.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('my_app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.isCollapsed = false;
}   
</script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you need specific (non-latest) version of both angular and bootstrap!  I'll pass on that!