# AngularJs ui.bootstrap issues - collapse not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am trying to make **ui.bootstrap** module work in Angularjs application. 
Here is the code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learn Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="uiApp" ng-controller="uiController">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    Toggle Panel
  </a>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
          Click here to collapse: {{isCollapsed}}
        </a>
      </h4>
            </div>
            <div collapse={{isCollapsed}}>
                <div class="panel-body"> This Section should collapse
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre><code>{{ isCollapsed }}</code></pre>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('uiApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])

.controller('uiController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong. 
I found the following question in stackoverflow,

[collapse transition not working with angular's UI Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178573/collapse-transition-not-working-with-angulars-ui-bootstrap)

but it did not help.

I tried in plunker - [click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZuzG0N00vPAWpw9kBifg?p=preview)
It doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I replaced

```
 <div collapse={{isCollapsed}}>
```

with

```
<div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
```